# Set user name in every commit

Tags: git

We will use the same user in our server to do a commit in git. So, how can I config the user name when I do a commit?

Example:

```
git add -A 
git commit -m "mensage" -user="User A"
```

Comment: Can you explain your environment? Why are you creating all your commits on one account on one machine? Superficially it would seem that you are not taking advantage of any of the features of a dVCS that git gives you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual of git-commit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-commit):

```
--author=<author>
  Override the commit author.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the user name per-repo by typing `git config user.name "my name"` and `git config user.email "me@example.com"` in the working directory for that repo. If you want to change user names between commits, you can use the same thing.

Comment: I know this, It's because I want change this every time, so the BloodyWorld answer is better for me :)